# Latex, Table caption won't go left

Tags: tables, graphics, horizontal-alignment, captions

I am having a problem with my table. I think it is because it is bigger than the width of the page. I don't know how to allign the legend left, doesn't matter what I do it is still centered. I appreciate any help. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{myformat}{\captionsetup{labelfont = bf,justification = raggedleft} #1#2\\#3}

\begin{document}





\begin{table}[htpb]
    \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
    \renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}
    \captionsetup{format = myformat}
    \caption{Results for Re = 40.}
    \raggedleft
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccl}
        \toprule
        Reference & Cd    & L/D   & a/D   & b/D   & $\theta_s$  & Remark \\
        \midrule
        \cite{Tritton1959} & 1.57  & -     & -     & -     & -     & Experimental \\
        \cite{Constanceau1977} & -     & 2.13  & 0.76  & 0.59  & 53.5  & Experimental \\
        \cite{Rengel1999} & 1.61  & 2.23  & 0.72  & 0.58  & 54.06 & FVM 180x180 \\
        \cite{Wanderley2008} & 1.56  & 2.29  & 0.73  & 0.6   & 53.08 & FDM 200x200 
        \\
        Present Study & 1.55  & 2.06  & 0.72  & 0.6   & 53.9  & FVM 200x200 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    \raggedleft
    \label{tab:table1}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide a MWE which can be compiled. I edited your code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to left-align the caption, you should be using raggedright, not raggedleft, in the argument of `\captionformat`. You should also get rid of the two standalone `\raggedleft` directives.

You may also want to align the numbers in the data columns on their respective decimal markers. The code below gives an example of how to do this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,caption,siunitx}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,
              justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=off}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Table}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htpb]

\caption{Results for Re = 40.}\label{tab:table1}
%%%%\raggedleft
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{T{1.2}} T{2.2} l @{}}
\toprule
Reference            & {Cd}  & {L/D} & {a/D} & {b/D} & {$\theta_s$} & Remark \\
\midrule
\cite{Tritton1959}    & 1.57 & {--} & {--} & {--} & {--} & Experimental \\
\cite{Constanceau1977}& {--} & 2.13 & 0.76 & 0.59 & 53.5 & Experimental \\
\cite{Rengel1999}     & 1.61 & 2.23 & 0.72 & 0.58 & 54.06& FVM 180$\times$180 \\
\cite{Wanderley2008}  & 1.56 & 2.29 & 0.73 & 0.6  & 53.08& FDM 200$\times$200
\\
Present Study         & 1.55 & 2.06 & 0.72 & 0.6  & 53.9 & FVM 200$\times$200 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%%%%\raggedleft
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry to ask but what exactly does it mean? \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{4}{T{1.2}} T{2.2} l @{}}

Comment: @LeonardoGuerreiro - Note first the code that defines the column type `T`; it's basically a space-saving way of setting up columns of type `S` which, in turn, are provided by the `siunitx` package. I assume you know what the `l` column type stands for. The string `*{4}{T{1.2}}` means "4 columns of type `T`, setting aside enough space for 1 digit before the decimal marker and 2 digits after the decimal marker." The string `T{2.2}` means "1 column of type `T`, setting aside enough space for 2 digits both before and after the decimal marker." Finally, `@{}` suppresses whitespace padding.

Comment: Thank you, solved it!